# React admin not asking for password

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Simple page given

```
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';

import * as React from "react";
import apiDataProvider from './apiDataProvider';
import apiAuthProvider from './apiAuthProvider';

const dataProvider = apiDataProvider('https://example.com/api/v1');

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={apiAuthProvider}>
       <Resource name="campaign" list={ListGuesser} />
    </Admin>
);


export default App;
```

apiDataProvider used for url customization, probably there's better solution

```
const endPoint = 'https://example.com/api/v1'

const apiAuthProvider = {
    login: ({ username, password }) => {
        console.log('login');
        const request = new Request(endPoint+'/sign-in/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }),
          headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        });
        return fetch(request)
          .then(response => {
            if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
              throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(auth => {
            localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(auth));
          })
          .catch(() => {
            throw new Error('Network error')
          });    
      }, 
    logout: () => {
        console.log('logout');
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        const request = new Request(endPoint+'/sign-out/', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ }),
          headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        });
        return fetch(request)
          .then(response => {
            if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
              throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(auth => {
            localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(auth));
          })
          .catch(() => {
            throw new Error('Network error')
          });    
        },
    checkAuth: () => {
        console.log('checkAuth', localStorage.getItem('username'));
        return localStorage.getItem('username') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
    },
    checkError:  (error) => {
        console.log('checkError');
        const status = error.status;
        if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
            localStorage.removeItem('username');
            return Promise.reject();
        }
        // other error code (404, 500, etc): no need to log out
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    getIdentity: () => {
        try {
            const { id, fullName, avatar } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
            return Promise.resolve({ id, fullName, avatar });
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }    
    },
    getPermissions: () => Promise.resolve(''),
};

export default apiAuthProvider;
```

On load "/" it calls logout twice, queries for campaign list (custom url), gets 401 and calls logout url again.

[image]

On the page I can see "Please login to continue" message, but no login window. Login form is available on /login. Why RA doesn't redirect to login form?

Comment: Sorry, but you have a real mess in the sources, you save in localStorage with the 'auth' key,
and then try to read their 'username' key, also unclear what you save after logout?

Comment: It's actually fixed but problem remains.